# What tools do you use to connect to AWS Athena via JDBC

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, amazon-athena

I am trying to connect to AWS Athena via my Windows as well as Mac system. My goal is to have a SQL Editor that I can use to perform quick research about the data. I was trying to find tools and tutorials for connecting to Athena. So far I have only found some tutorials around SQL Workbench. What are some other tools that you guys leverage and is there something particular that you like about that tool and how easy was it to setup either on Windows/Mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) for connecting to Athena. It has served the purpose so far. Once you import the JDBC drivers(you can download them from AWS's [site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html)) the tool itself is pretty straight forward to setup. The URL that you can use to connect can be seen here -

```
jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=<AWS Region>;User=<AWS Access Key>;Password=<AWS Secret Key>;S3OutputLocation=<S3 folder>
```

I'm pasting the "Overview" of SQuirreL below:

> SQuirreL SQL Client is a graphical Java program that will allow you to
>   view the structure of a JDBC compliant database, browse the data in
>   tables, issue SQL commands etc, see Introduction. The minimum version
>   of Java supported is 1.6.x as of SQuirreL version 3.0. See the Old
>   Versions page for versions of SQuirreL that will work with older
>   versions of Java.
>
> SQuirreL's functionality can be extended through the use of plugins.
>
> A short introduction can be found here. To see the change history
>   (including changes not yet released) click here.
>
> For a more detailed introduction see the English or German of our
>   paper on SQuirreL.
>
> Susan Cline graciously took the time to document the steps she
>   followed to setup an Apache Derby database from scratch and use the
>   SQuirreL SQL Client to explore it.
>
> Quite some time ago Kulvir Singh Bhogal wrote a great tutorial on
>   SQuirreL and published it at the IBM developerWorks site. He has
>   kindly allowed us to mirror it locally. The tutorial is not really up
>   to date but especially for doing the first steps it is still of help.
>
> SQuirrel was originally released under the GNU General Public License.
>   Since version 1.1beta2 it has been released under the GNU Lesser
>   General Public License.

Another tool that I have used pretty extensively is [SQL Workbench](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/). This is also sort of recommended on the [AWS site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html). The is good, but I found that it would hang up sometimes and I would loose my work.

Both of these can be easily downloaded from the links provided or if you like to use CLI then Homebrew can be used on MacBook or [Chocolatey on windows](https://chocolatey.org/packages/sql-workbench)

Some other tools that you can use are [*DataGrip* by JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/). Guide to setup the tool can be seen [here](https://medium.com/datamindedbe/connect-to-aws-athena-using-datagrip-c34762e37a17). The functionality of *DataGrip* is also built into [*IntelliJ Ultimate Edition*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

DB Visualizer is another tool that can be used to connect to AWS Athena the guide to connect can be found [here](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/athena-jdbc-dbv.rst)

TeamSQL and Razor SQL are some other tools that you can leverage.

Answer (score 1):

One of the strengths of JDBC drivers is that as long as a tool supports JDBC, you can use it for any data source which has a JDBC driver. First, get the JAR file for the JDBC driver for Athena here: [Amazon Athena Connect with JDBC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html).  Java works across platforms, so as long as you have Java in your Windows/Mac environment, you should have no problem using any of these tools.

The tool [SQL Workbench/J](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/getting-started.html) is fairly popular, but I find it frustrating to work with when switching between multiple databases.

Another tool is [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), which also supports JDBC drivers. I prefer it, but it looks a little less pretty than SQL Workbench/J. Once you've downloaded the JDBC driver, configure it in SquirrelSQL by going to Drivers and then adding a new one. Label it "Amazon Athena" and specify the Example URL as `jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=[Region];User=
[AccessKey];Password=[SecretKey];S3OutputLocation=[Output];
[Property1]=[Value1];[Property2]=[Value2];...` 
Leave the Website URL Blank, but specify the Class Name as `com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver`. Add the .jar file of the JDBC driver to the "Extra Class Path" page.

Once you've set up the driver, you can set up connections by going to the **Alias** tab and hitting the plus sign. Simply fill in the values in the example URL to point to your data source. Once you're connected, you're good to start writing queries.

SquirrelSQL saves the connection information for you, allowing you to quickly jump between data sources, and makes it easy to write multiple queries in one input window, with their outputs going to separate tabs in the output pane.  I've used it for database, exploration, DDL, and regular day-to-day tasks with data. It's been good for most anything I've connected it to. It is definitely not perfect, but it's getting better all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a Docker SQL Editor that you can use to perform quick research about the data.

But I suggest two ways.

One is Offline/Online and with installation methods, which you can use with a fixed connection.

The first solution is to select a system as a server and connect to it from other operating systems. This is the traditional / old solution.

In the second solution you just need to be trained to work with Docker. This is a newer and more popular solution.

> if you want use MySQL in MAC read this article :
>
> [Installing MySQL in a Mac OS X environment](https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_services/install_mysql_mac_os_x_environment.html)
>
> If you want use MySQL in windows read this article :
>
> [How to Install MySQL on Windows](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-mysql-windows/)

But you need a synchronous space for use MySQL or other DBMS you can use docker.
Docker is very Flexible . But you need connect to internet.

> If you want use Docker read this article and view docker site :
>
> **Docker** : [SITE](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)
>
> **Docker Doc** : [Start a Remote MySQL Server with Docker quickly](https://medium.com/@backslash112/start-a-remote-mysql-server-with-docker-quickly-9fdff22d23fd)